# Jquery "live" event not firing

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with the live event which is necessary as I am dynamically adding elements to a page.

A regular click event works fine. I want to know why the live click event is failing. There are instructions in the demo I set up at JSFiddle. Maybe someone can explain to me why this is happening.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/MezfS/2/

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Mully can you post what works for you. Update the demo above and post your link - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with delegate and allowing the click event to bubble as far as the anchor:

```
$('#pui-tabs a').delegate('.tab-close', 'click', function(e) {
        tabselector.tabs('remove', tabselector.tabs('option', 'selected'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MezfS/21/

Answer (score 3):

"live" events behave differently than normal events handler. When you bind a live event, an event handler is appended to one of the topmost elements in the page (say body, or document). Since when you click anywhere on the page, you are also clicking on the body, the event will bubble up. For example, you click on a link, which is contained in a div, which is contained in the body, the event will be triggered for the link, the for the div, then for the body.

When the event reach the body, the "live" event handler will look at it, and if the source of the click matches your selector, it will trigger your function.

UNLESS one of the handlers on the link or the div stopped the event propagation. In that case, the event is stopped and will not bubble up, never reaching the "live" handler.

I suppose that jQuery UI places an handler on the tab, to capture clicks, and that handler is actually stopping propagation, making the "live" handler useless.

Comment: Thanks - that's interesting. When the .close-tab span is placed outside the anchor it works but I need it to fire inside the anchor.

Comment: Good point, but if you put an alert right above `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`, it should fire in any case, right? But it doesn't.

Comment: Was digging into the source to verify before posting, and that is exactly what's happening.

Comment: I think karim79 suggestion is right, choose his answer as the right one, i didn't know of the delegate method, which seems to be exactly to circumvent this problem. Keep my answer and an explanation, but his answer as a solution.

Comment: @Nathan yes, but it's not Haraldo's e.stopImmediatePropagation() that is causeing the problem, it is a similar line inside jQuery UI, that jmar777 seems to have found (i was too lazy to search for it :) )

Comment: So the .live will not fire because its not bubbling up far enough. Something in UI is stopping it from propagating - right?

Comment: @Haraldo it seems we all arrived to this conclusion.

Comment: The milestone Jquery UI 1.9m5 doesn't seem to have this issue. This scenario just isn't a problem. Anyway - thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

`.live` relies on the event bubbling all the way up to document, and you are stopping the immediate propagation of the your handler, thereby stopping it from working. Try this instead:

```
$('li[id=^="tab"]').delegate(".tab-close", "click", function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    tabselector.tabs('remove', tabselector.tabs('option', 'selected'));
});
```

Comment: I've tried your example in the JSFiddle demo in my post but it does not work. The issue is that the live event is not even being fired.